# Using TransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync to upload root folder and its contents

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a folder's contents, all sub-directories *and* the initial folder itself. In the example below, I want to select `C` and have `file1C`, `file2C` *and* `FolderC` uploaded as well:

```
FolderA
-FolderB
-FolderC
--File1C
--File2C
```

The following code will upload everything in `A`, but including folder `B` (which I do not want)

```
await fileTransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync(source + "/FolderA", bucketName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The following code will upload everything in `C`, but excluding `FolderC` itself (which I do not want)

```
await fileTransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync(source + "/FolderC", bucketName, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: As per your search option, you're currently uploading everything beneath the source folder. Try experimenting with other search options or uploading specific files (maybe in a loop) to have more control over what you're uploading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code I don't believe it's possible to use a single command to upload the parent directory and all of it's contents.

[`UploadDirectoryCommand.ExecuteAsync`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Transfer/Internal/_bcl45%2Bnetstandard/UploadDirectoryCommand.cs#L31) calls into [`UploadDirectoryCommand.GetFiles`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/S3/Custom/Transfer/Internal/_bcl45%2Bnetstandard/UploadDirectoryCommand.cs#L93) to get the list of items to upload.

But that's just using the framework's [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_) method, which doesn't appear to offer the necessary enumeration.

I'd advise making 2 calls:

1. Create `FolderC` in S3 if it doesn't yet exist
2. Then use `TransferUtility.UploadDirectoryAsync` to upload the contents.

Comment: Not the answer i wanted, but perhaps the answer i needed?? Puts my mind at peace to know someone agrees i need to have two lines of code, when a single call should have done it... ;)